# How to instantiate a stream from a buffer in wxPython Phoenix?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, wxpython, buffer

Some context:

- wxPython version 3.0.3.dev1836+f764b32 gtk2 (phoenix)
- Python 2.7.3
- Ubuntu 12.04

I am trying to create an image from a stream.
The future image is currently loaded from memory into a buffer.

I have already tried things like:

```
image_stream = wx.MemoryOutputStream()  # error: no attribute 'MemoryOutputStream'
image_stream.Write( image_buffer, buffer_size )
image = wx.Image( stream )
bitmap = wx.Bitmap( image )
```

Basically, `wx.InputStream`, `wx.OutputStream` and all of their ancestors are abstract-classes, I cannot instantiate them.

As you can see [here](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/InputStream.html#sub-classes-known-subclasses) and [there](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/OutputStream.html#sub-classes-known-subclasses), the documentation for their sub-classes seems to be missing.

It also follows from the error written in the above code that those classes are not implemented yet.

Is there a way to instantiate such stream in wxPython Phoenix? Or a workaround?

By the way, as I will write and then read from the stream, should it be an input stream, an output stream or one and then the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wxImage` objects can be created directly from any object that supports the Python buffer interface, (bytearrays memoryviews, numpy arrays, etc.)  See [this section](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/MigrationGuide.html#wx-image-and-python-buffer-objects) in the Migration Guide and also the `__init__` and `Create` method overloads in the [API documentation](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/Image.html) which have a parameter named `data`.

In addition, any Python "file-like object" can be automatically converted to the wx stream classes, so the Image constructor and Create method overloads which accept a `stream` parameters can use any compatible object (an open file, a StringIO, etc.) automatically, so you shouldn't have any need to make a `wx.InputStream` or `wx.OutputStream`.

Comment: I finally used: `img = wx.ImageFromBuffer( width, height, image_buffer )` and `bitmap = wx.Bitmap( img )`. With `image_buffer` being a numpy array in RGB format.